# Configuring MYSQL with Datamapper

Tags: mysql, ruby, sinatra, datamapper

I've long been a user of sqlite3 (with rails) and I never got a chance to try mysql, until now. I need to configure to use it along with Datamapper. Following the [tutorial](http://datamapper.org/getting-started.html) I need to install the dm-mysql-adapter using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

My `.rb` file contains the following code:

```
require 'data_mapper'
DataMapper.setup(:default, "mysql://user:password@hostname/database")

class Post
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id         , Serial
  property :title      , String
  property :body       , Text
  property :created_at , DateTime
end
```

Which doesn't run and gives me the following error:

```
in `require': no such file to load -- dm-mysql-adapter (LoadError)
```

I believe, I need to set up a username and password to get mysql up and running and then establish a connection with Datamapper. Can someone please guide me.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Nope, you'll need to install `dm-mysql-adapter` via gem.

Comment: Yup I did that and I included it in my code. The code ran fine but how  can I see if a database was successfully created (like one can see a development.db file using sqlite with rails)

Comment: The existence of `development.db` doesn't tell you anything. Grab any mysql client (the simplest one is probably `mysql` on the command line) and do some introspection.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're probably getting wrong is that you haven't installed your mysql server. 
Do this:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

During the installation, you'll be prompted for a password. Now your mysql server should be running. Use this command to check if it is running:

```
sudo netstat -tap | grep mysql
```

Now you need to login as a user and create a database which you'll use in your datamapper

```
mysql -u root -p
```

and when logged in, write

```
$ create database my_db;
```

Now in put these values in the datamapper setup call for eg.

```
DataMapper.setup(:default, "mysql://root:password@localhost/my_db")
```

Hope that helps ;)

Answer (score 1):

try installing this gem

```
gem install dm-mysql-adapter
```